# De-prettify table in Excel worksheet before save-as tab-delimited txt file

Tags: excel, csv

Frequently I get data as "pretty tables" in many worksheets in an Excel workbook. By "pretty" I mean that there is explanatory text at the top and bottom of every worksheet, headers have merged cells, there are blanks lines between the header and the first data row, there are blank columns between data columns, etc.

[image: Here is a screen grab of part of one offender.]

Is there a best practice for reducing manual labor here?

One approach could be to fix all of these tables in Excel. Another could be to save "as-is" to tab-delimited txt, manually select and import the data rows, drop the blank columns, and manually enter the header information. I tend to do the later, but even this is fairly manual.

What are the pros doing? When I do it this way I feel like the guy who doesn't know about cut and paste.

FWIW, I use Python, Stata, and R for most things, but I'm open to any tool that simplifies this process. Thanks!

Comment: I once had a project like this. It took me two weeks to remember how to do enough [tag:Perl] to match all the typical patterns and chomp and chop my way through, which saved me two weeks of cut and paste. Somehow, I still considered this a victory, even though it would now take me three weeks (I'm older) to remember how to do the exact same thing again in [tag:Perl]. But, I'd still recommend learning some [tag:Perl], [tag:awk], or similar to do the preprocessing [tag:R] is not intended to do.

Comment: I teach all my users to use the "insert table".  Then you can loop through the tables in the workbook and ignore all the fluff.

Comment: @A.Webb -- Thanks! A learned a little awk over the summer after getting a folder of ~1000 Excel workbooks. It's reassuring to hear that wasn't a crazy idea. I guess there isn't a silver bullet, just a set of tools that saves time in the long run.

Comment: @Jesse -- Thanks for the tip! I have macros that loop through the sheets in a workbook (or workbooks in a folder), but I didn't this was also possible at the table level, which solves the header/footer problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest the amount of automation that I use in the process of cleaning data depends on the number of times I have to do it. For me I think modifying the files in Excel via macro.

If your files always have the same format (for a particular task) you can simply record a macro of the steps you are doing to clean them up, and save them in your personal workbook

If they are slightly different but have variations on a theme you can modify the recorded marco (ideally factoring out into functions like `DeleteTopRows` and `DeleteEmptyColumns` which would accept different parameters depending on the input file)

I think Excel VBA is the easiest place to work from for this type of job because the excel app can help with a lot of built in functions. For example in your sheet above `Range("10:11").Delete` will remove them.

Comment: Thanks! I have macros that write all sheets in a workbook to .txt, but adding more of the pre-processing to Excel is a good idea. Thanks for the pointers.